# Grabbing specific months first date and lastdate in PHP

Tags: php

```
function firstOfMonth() {
return date("m/d/Y", strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00'));
}

function lastOfMonth() {
return date("m/d/Y", strtotime('-1 second',strtotime('+1 month',strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00'))));
}
```

is what i have to get the current month's first day date and last day date.

Now i wish to change it alittle, so in both functions they have a param with $month, where $month holds the number of the month I would like to get the first date and last date from.

Example if i do firstOfMonth(1), I would like it to return 2012-01-01 and lastOfMonth(1) it should return 2012-01-31

How can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the first and last days of a give month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541938/how-to-get-the-first-and-last-days-of-a-give-month)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-02-01');

// first day
echo $date->format('d-m-Y');

// t = days in month, minutes one to go to the last.
$date->modify(sprintf('+%d day', $date->format('t')-1));

// Last day
echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , if you are using PHP 5.3+,

```
$query_date = '2012-01-01';
$date = new DateTime($query_date);
//First day of month
$date->modify('first day of this month');
$firstday= $date->format('Y-m-d');
//Last day of month
$date->modify('last day of this month');
$lastday= $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

For finding next month last date, modify as follows,

```
$date->modify('last day of 1 month');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

and so on..