# If date string found to be between dates, return pay_period_start & pay_period_end. How?

Tags: php, datetime

The following code **works if I manually type in every day for every single month** in each hard coded array.

I then loop through the arrays for a match and if I find it, I return the first index and the last index value of that array. These are the pay period start and end dates later to be used with mysql select queries.

```
// MOUNTAIN DAYLIGHT SAVINGS TIME
date_default_timezone_set('MST7MDT');

// = PHP Default TimeZone
//print 'MOUNTAIN DAYLIGHT SAVINGS TIME';
//print '<p>';

// = MySQL CURRDATE() in MySQL DATETIME Format.
$php_current_date = date('Y-m-d');

// 2019 Pay Periods - MONTHLY

$parent_array = array(
1 => array('2019-01-01','2019-01-31'),
2 => array('2019-02-01','2019-02-28'),
3 => array('2019-03-01','2019-03-31'),
4 => array('2019-04-01','2019-04-30'),
5 => array('2019-05-01','2019-05-31'),
6 => array('2019-06-01','2019-06-30'),
7 => array('2019-07-01','2019-07-31'),
8 => array('2019-08-01','2019-08-31'),
9 => array('2019-09-01','2019-09-30'),
10 => array('2019-10-01','2019-10-31'),
11 => array('2019-11-01','2019-11-30'),
12 => array('2019-12-01','2019-12-31'),
13 => array('2020-01-01','2020-01-31'),
14 => array('2020-02-01','2020-02-29'),
15 => array('2020-03-01','2020-03-31'),
16 => array('2020-04-01','2020-04-30'),
17 => array('2020-05-01','2020-05-31'),
18 => array('2020-06-01','2020-06-30'),
19 => array('2020-07-01','2020-07-31'),
20 => array('2020-08-01','2020-08-31'),
21 => array('2020-09-01','2020-09-30'),
22 => array('2020-10-01','2020-10-31'),
23 => array('2020-11-01','2020-11-30'),
24 => array('2020-12-01','2020-12-31')
);


$current_pay_period_start = '';
$current_pay_period_end = '';


// For each child Array of date Strings inside parent Array of arrays...
foreach($parent_array as $child_array){

   // Speculate the variable name as $result_found while searching each child Array of date Strings
   // for the Current date in *Mountain Daylight Savings Time
   $result_found = in_array($php_current_date, $child_array);

    // if we have a match...
    if ($result_found) {

        // GET LEFT-MOST index and assign it to a variable.
        $current_pay_period_start = current($child_array);

        // GET RIGHT-MOST index and assign it to another variable.
        $current_pay_period_end = end($child_array);
        // Add a day for mysql query logic...
        // because mysql uses < instead of =< for comparison in the query the follows...
        $current_pay_period_end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($current_pay_period_end . ' + 1 days'));

        /* 
        Following Works ONLY on direct access.
        Debug Only.
        Eg. localhost/folder/filename.php
        */


        print 'Php Current Date: ' . $php_current_date;
        print '<br>';
        print 'Current Pay Period Start: ' . $current_pay_period_start;
        print '<br>';
        print 'Current Pay Period End: ' . $current_pay_period_end;
        exit;

    }
}
```

**I have tried to implement the solution below** but, I keep getting errors related to me not being able to compare date strings... It seems I have learned to find date strings in an array of arrays but they aren't really dates as far as php is concerned.

```
/**
 * @param DateTime $date Date that is to be checked if it falls between $startDate and $endDate
 * @param DateTime $startDate Date should be after this date to return true
 * @param DateTime $endDate Date should be before this date to return true
 * return bool
 */
function isDateBetweenDates(DateTime $date, DateTime $startDate, DateTime $endDate) {
    return $date > $startDate && $date < $endDate;
}

$fromUser = new DateTime("2012-03-01");
$startDate = new DateTime("2012-02-01 00:00:00");
$endDate = new DateTime("2012-04-30 23:59:59");

echo isDateBetweenDates($fromUser, $startDate, $endDate);
```

Here's how I try to call it and get the error...

```
isDateBetweenDates($php_current_date, $current_pay_period_start, $current_pay_period_end);
```

Comment: `because mysql uses < instead of =< for comparison in the query the follows` what this means? Mysql supports `<=` too but you must write it correctly

Comment: It caters to a Select query with a range of `1 => array('2019-01-01','2019-01-31 23:59:59')`. Is this incorrect, obsolete or a poor approach? I am open to suggestions. Now I am thinking of creating the child arrays with ` 23:59:59` at the end of each.

Comment: I would try to come up with a solution using `strtotime` with a relative date like `strtotime("last day of month")` instead of this date range thing you are trying.

Comment: Excellent point. I hard coded the dates to free myself from having to mess with leap years and all the not fun stuff involved with date and time. I wish to stored these ranges as string because they have already been verified in Excel and then only convert to date when I search. The conversion is so I don't need 365 array indexes per year.

Comment: @ASPiRE the date/time functions in php already account for leap years and such. I highly recommend using them.

Comment: Ok. Will I encounter any date time compatibility issues between php and mysql when using php date/time functions? When I search mysql for `'2019-01-01','2019-01-31'` is mysql actually searching `'2019-01-01','2019-01-31 23:59:59'` or do I still have to `$current_pay_period_end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($current_pay_period_end . ' + 1 days'));`?

Comment: Before you use the date in a query, you can change the format of it.

Comment: I can. Is mysql's interpretation of `'2019-01-01','2019-01-31'` the same as `'2019-01-01','2019-01-31 23:59:59'` or MUST I ALSO format for this in php as well?

Comment: Honestly I think it depends on if your mysql fields are dates or datetimes. I would just do some edge case testing, but either way you should be able to get it to work. Also this should help you get the first and last days of the month easily. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541938/how-to-get-the-first-and-last-days-of-a-given-month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have wrote the following for you, that compares the two dates from your array. Hopefully it will help!

```
        $php_current_date = date('Y-m-d');
        $parent_array = array(
            1 => array('2019-01-01','2019-01-31'),
            2 => array('2019-02-01','2019-02-28'),
            3 => array('2019-03-01','2019-03-31'),
            4 => array('2019-04-01','2019-04-30'),
            5 => array('2019-05-01','2019-05-31'),
            6 => array('2019-06-01','2019-06-30'),
            7 => array('2019-07-01','2019-07-31'),
            8 => array('2019-08-01','2019-08-31'),
            9 => array('2019-09-01','2019-09-30'),
            10 => array('2019-10-01','2019-10-31'),
            11 => array('2019-11-01','2019-11-30'),
            12 => array('2019-12-01','2019-12-31'),
            13 => array('2020-01-01','2020-01-31'),
            14 => array('2020-02-01','2020-02-29'),
            15 => array('2020-03-01','2020-03-31'),
            16 => array('2020-04-01','2020-04-30'),
            17 => array('2020-05-01','2020-05-31'),
            18 => array('2020-06-01','2020-06-30'),
            19 => array('2020-07-01','2020-07-31'),
            20 => array('2020-08-01','2020-08-31'),
            21 => array('2020-09-01','2020-09-30'),
            22 => array('2020-10-01','2020-10-31'),
            23 => array('2020-11-01','2020-11-30'),
            24 => array('2020-12-01','2020-12-31')
        );
        foreach ($parent_array as $child_array) {
            //compare dates using strtotime, did the conversion in the if statement to retain the original date format, for output if results are found.
            if (strtotime($php_current_date) >= strtotime($child_array[0]) && strtotime($php_current_date) <= strtotime($child_array[1])) {
                // match found...
                $current_pay_period_start = $child_array[0];
                $current_pay_period_end = $child_array[1];
                print 'Php Current Date: ' . $php_current_date;
                print '<br>';
                print 'Current Pay Period Start: ' . $current_pay_period_start;
                print '<br>';
                print 'Current Pay Period End: ' . $current_pay_period_end;
                exit;
            }
        }
```

I have tested it and the following is outputted:

```
Php Current Date: 2019-03-07
Current Pay Period Start: 2019-03-01
Current Pay Period End: 2019-03-31
```

Hopefully this will help!

Comment: Fantastic. I will be able to use this for weekly, bi-weekly, monthly, quarterly, yearly.